# "He wore a trailing arm from someone" What does this mean?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I was watching/reading World cup soccer live updates and read following sentence.

"Lichtsteiner is down holding his face. Replays show that he wore a trailing arm from Miranda. He’s up now and seems to be fine."

What does "he wore a trailing arm from someone" mean? It sounds like it means a player was hit by another player's arm. Maybe this sentence also suggests the hit was an accident since the word "trailing arm." Am I correct? why do we use the word "wear" in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sportscaster is using

> **wore**

**figuratively** as an **analogy**. Miranda's arm was in ***close contact*** to Lichtsteiner's face and remained there for a time as if he was ***wearing a piece of clothing***

> **Lichtsteiner was wearing Miranda's arm**

The significance is that prolonged contact is not allowed and is player interference.

Comment: Peter might well be correct and either way, "he wore a trailing arm…" is hardly great English.